# StringContent vs ObjectContent

Tags: c#, json, serialization, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I am using System.Net.Http's HttpClient to call a REST API with "POST" 
using the following code:

```
using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(
                                           HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(request)) { })
{
     response = await httpClient.PostAsync(request, objectContent);
}
```

The "objectContent" is currently this -

```
objectContent = new ObjectContent(jsonContent.GetType(),
                                  jsonContent,
                                  new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I was wondering what difference it makes if this was a StringContent rather than an ObjectContent like this?

```
objectContent = new StringContent(content);
objectContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
```

Both work fine. Because it is JSON, i tend to assume that StringContent would make sense. But when is ObjectContent to be used because pretty much all content sent is a "string".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I was wondering what difference it makes if this was a StringContent
>   rather than an ObjectContent like this?

In your example there won't be any difference. `ObjectContent` simply allows a "wider" range of types to be sent via `HttpClient`, while `StringContent` is narrower for `string` values only, such as JSON.

`StringContent` is a slim wrapper around `ByteArrayContent`, and actually stores the value passed as a `byte[]`. You simply get the benefit of not needing to transform your `string` back and forth.

**Edit:**

Given the fact that you're posting a JSON, you can even make it less verbose by using [`HttpClientExtensions.PostAsJsonAsync<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

```
await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, json);
```

Comment: Makes sense. In my case, the response is always expected to be "application/json" from the REST APIs and hence I would go with StringContent

Comment: @Patrick - Thanks for highlighting. I missed and was responding with a comment.

Comment: @Lalman Perhaps `PostAsJsonAsync` would be an even better, less verbose approach to posting a JSON. See my edit.

Comment: I'm having issues with PostAsJsonAsync since it's not including Content-Length for the ObjectContent. My Json data isn't actually posting to the API. It's posting over with Chunked transfer encoding. Any suggestions (outside of reverting to StringContent)?

Answer (score 3):

If someone will search how to send request by PostAsync in .NET Core 2.1:
I did not found PostAsJsonAsync method in HttpClient, but your solution with setting:

```
objectContent = new StringContent(content);
objectContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
```

"do the job" perfectly also in .NET Core.

Edit:

Additionally If you want add your own header you can type:

```
objectContent.Headers.Add("Your header", "Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

ObjectContent is used to format more complex Mime types using built-in or custom-written formatters. It is OK to use ObjectContent for a simple string as well, it doesn't make much difference except for the performance which (IMHO and not checked) may be better with StringContent, since it may have been optimized specifically for strings

Comment: Thanks Denis. I would be running a performance test to ascertain performance difference, if there is any!

Comment: I wish you would have written **how** to use simple string as ObjectContent as well. Just found myself trying to use a generic function that creates the HTTPRequestMessage with ObjectContent and a JsonMediaTypeFormatter: ```new ObjectContent<TValue>(value, jsonFormatter);```. But when passed a pre-serialized json string as value, it messes up the string by adding a bunch of "\". Anyhow, my search goes on.

Comment: @micnil when using `ObjectContent` you pass a `jsonFormatter`. In your case the one you passed adds the "\". So you can either pass a non-serialized object which will be serialized by the formatter, or change the formatter to another one that won't add the "\".